# Possible to set the size and font of text of GtkButton with Glade?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade, gtkbutton, gtkcssprovider

is it possible to set the size and font of text of a GtkButton with Glade (Version 3.38.2) ?

If yes, how?  :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Style classes" under Common tab, Widget Attributes.

Then if you add "large" style class you can do css:

```
.large {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size:32px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Provide this to the GTK widget form:

```
css = b"""
.large {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size:32px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 2px;
    padding: 8px;
}"""
        style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        style_provider.load_from_data(css)

        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
            Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
            style_provider,
            Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
        )
```

As in that example: https://gist.github.com/fcwu/5794494